# How is "continuous wiring" defined in context of the 2017 NEC code?

Tags: wiring, nec, afci

First, some context: About AFCI protection in Dwelling Units, NEC 2017:

> **210.12(A)** All 120-volt, single-phase, 15- and 20-ampere branch circuits supplying outlets or devices installed [...] shall be protected by [...]
>
> ... **(4)** A listed outlet branch-circuit type arc-fault circuit interrupter installed at the first outlet on the branch circuit in combination with a listed branch-circuit overcurrent protective device where ***all*** of the following conditions are met:
>
> - a. The branch-circuit **wiring shall be continuous** from the branch-circuit overcurrent device to the outlet branch-circuit arc-fault circuit  interrupter.
> - b. The maximum length of the branch-circuit wiring from the branch-circuit overcurrent device to the first outlet shall not exceed 15.2 m (50 ft) for a 14 AWG conductor or 21.3 m (70 ft) for a 12 AWG conductor.
> - c. The first outlet box in the branch circuit shall be marked to indicate that it is the first outlet of the circuit.
> - d. The **combination of** the branch-circuit overcurrent device and outlet branch-circuit AFCI shall be identified as meeting the requirements for a system combination-type AFCI and shall be listed as such.

**So how is "continuous wiring" defined in context of the 2017 NEC code?** It is not listed in its Definitions chapter. Is it the same as electrical continuity? Mechanical continuity? Not-interrupted-by-switches-that-are-potentially-open-continuity? or something else? In a different context, Mike Holt states [1]:

> Conductors in raceways must be **continuous** between all points of the system. This means you can't place splices in the raceway[...]

Is this correct? If so / if not: Can you provide a reference?

[1] [https://www.mikeholt.com/mojonewsarchive/NEC-HTML/HTML/Article-300-Wiring-Methods~20031029.htm](https://www.mikeholt.com/mojonewsarchive/NEC-HTML/HTML/Article-300-Wiring-Methods%7E20031029.htm)

Comment: I went ahead and edited your code cite, to line it up with SE formatting and include all the conditions, since they are an "And". .

Comment: NEC 2017 - **300.13 Mechanical and Electrical Continuity — Conductors. (A) General.** Conductors in raceways shall be continuous between outlets, boxes, devices, and so forth. There shall be no splice or tap within a raceway unless permitted by 300.15; 368.56(A); 376.56; 378.56; 384.56; 386.56; 388.56; or 390.7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Nope.  Nope nope nope.

### *You cannot use 210.12(A)(4) to put AFCI at an outlet*.

There are certain fairly rare cases where you can put AFCI at the first outlet.

However, there is a misconception that has turned into a regular "old wives' tale", that one can skip the expensive AFCI breaker and just slap an ACFI recep at the first outlet.  Oh no you can't!

Of course, now that it's turned into a wives' tale, everybody is running for the Codebook hellbound to find the supporting language.  The closest thing they find to support their preconceived notion is 210.12(A)(4). "That must be it!" they say.  And they stick a Post-It there ready to throw it in the inspector's face.

That wishful reading is possible if you totally ignore (4)(d): "blah blah **system combination-type AFCI** blah blah".  Go ogle that. That is a "married pair" of receptacle head-unit and trick breaker, both designed and UL-listed to work with each other.  *The section was added to Code at Cutler Hammer's request, to support exactly one product, [their SCAF20](https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/products/electrical-circuit-protection/circuit-breakers/system-combination-arc-fault-circuit-breaker.html)*.

Its killer feature is it uses Cutler Hammer's remote control breaker tech *to allow resetting the breaker from the outlet*. The outlet is just a "head unit" that controls the breaker.  So the guest can do it from the hotel room without calling the front desk.  Get it?

Now go back and re-read 210.12(A)(4). See how it was written for the SCAF20?  Bingo.  It is not applicable to general AFCI outlets at all.

Other than that, Mrs. Lincoln, how about your original question?

### Continuous means no splices.

A solid run of NM-B or whatever you're rolling.  No Tyco in-wall splices. No stopping at an intermediate junction box.  No feeding some lighting circuits. Note that options (1) through (4) require a breaker which actually is an AFCI breaker.  (5) through (6) don't, but they require conduit, and there's already a rule against splices in conduit.

Keep in mind that despite the name, AFCI is not anything like GFCI.  AFCI is mainly there to protect wires in the walls.  You can't put it at the first receptacle because that would leave the home-run totally unprotected.  That's only allowed in metal or concrete shelled conduit.

Comment: ...and after due consideration of my relationship to the mice (kill 'em all? good luck with that) and the rural fire department response time, I'm getting pretty good at bending EMT. But I am a weirdo, evidently.

Comment: The more I look at the SCAF20, the less I think it's actually remote control. Can you double-check that?

Comment: @JosephSible You know I haven't done a Big Clive on one, but why wouldn't it be?  Remote control breakers [are a core competency of Eaton](http://www.eaton.com/EatonCA/ProductsSolutions/Electrical/ProductsandServices/CircuitProtection/IndustrialMiniatureCircuitBreakers/RemoteControlledCircuitBreakers/index.htm). Their bog-standard R/C breaker doesn't allow R/C *overcurrent trip* reset, but that is probably just a UL requirement to keep idiots from automating breaker reset. Not an issue in a married pair where a human has to push a button.

Comment: They tend to make it very clear when a breaker is remote-controlled, and that one doesn't. Also, it looks like their breakers that are advertised as such have an extra override lever and extra wires for them. My impression is that the SCAF20 is just a regular circuit breaker with no special sauce inside, that detects parallel arc faults in the home run by them causing overcurrent, and an AFCI outlet, that detects parallel arc faults everywhere else and all series arc faults. (And that seems to be what https://iaeimagazine.org/magazine/features/whats-new-about-afcis-in-the-2014-nec/ says too.)

Comment: @JosephSible I've seen that magazine's pasta before, they're flailing around guessing. "regular breaker with no special sauce inside" - and let me guess, the AFCI is just a regular AFCI. The whole product is a lie/conspiracy with UL.  **That would sure be convenient if your goal is to rationalize AFCI receps**.  But *why does it have a neutral pigtail?*

Comment: Hmm, the presence of the neutral is a good point. Now I'm REALLY curious what's going on in that thing. Somewhat tangentially, I discovered this: https://www.nfpa.org/assets/files/AboutTheCodes/70/70_A2018_NEC_P02_SD_pcsubmittals.pdf (page 163). So apparently someone takes issue to that bit of code, and even if I wanted to shell out $400 for one, I may not be able to.

Comment: @JosephSible that looks like inter-manufacturer backbiting to me. But Leviton is pulling a scam; the entire block of 210.12(A)(4) is designed for the Eaton product. By their logic the entire block should be removed, but *they're arguing* only (d) should be removed to allow basically "the wive's tale". They argue furthere [here](https://www.legrand.us/-/media/brands/passandseymour/resources/white-paper/ps-white-paper_afci-point-of-use.ashx). NFPA saw right through it!   Surely the Eaton unit must be at least a parallel AFCI.